# Is it possible to use wordpress on some pages of my site only?

Tags: wordpress, web-development

I am making a website, and part of it will have dynamic content, as well as easier for me to manage as there will be less code involved.

for example, The website.com/home page, /users page and /payments etc pages are all static and managed by an admin panel that someone has built for me, with its own Database.

however I want to have a website.com/news  /blog   /contact pages, in which are built on wordpress, as it is much easier for me to make, since I have more experience with it, thus I can make contact forms to my email, dynamic blog posts, etc without needing to code it since im not that experienced with that.

I have done some research and have seen it is possible to host subdomains on different hosts, eg use Host 1 for the website.com, then redirect the DNS for sub.website.com to another host that uses wordpress, however is there a way so that I can make it so website.com/slug pages use wordpress and others do not? If so is it possible to do this on the same host, or will I need a different host and change the DNS for those /slugs?

Comment: Questions [specific to CMS's like WordPress](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are really best asked on their respective site, therefore this was migrated to WordPress Development for you.